# Is there a way of keeping data in the volatile memory while the device is on?

Tags: android, memory, lifecycle

I need to preserve some data and clear it when the device is turned off. It can't be persisted in any ways. It should only be in RAM.

Comment: I think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14133824/5109911

Comment: You can use a Broadcast Receiver with `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Unfortunately an application's memory can be wiped from the device whenever Android feels the need to clean up resources for other apps. Possibly the only way to do it is to keep a reference to the data in a Service, then re-download or re-create the data when the Service is eventually restored.

Comment: SharedPreferences saves to a file so that is not keeping it in RAM.